# How to hide/secure password by changing it to *

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I'm making a program where the user is asked for a password and if the password input is correct, it will display the name `MSG3` and ID `MSG4`. The code below runs well but I just want the password input to be seen as the * character rather than plain string. If it's also possible I would like to limit the user's input to only 3 characters. I am new to this language, hope anyone can help!

Here is the code:

```
.DATA 
MSG1 DB 10,13,’Enter Password: $’
MSG2 DB 10,13,’Incorrect Password! $’
MSG3 DB 10,13,’Sam Smith $’ 
MSG4 DB 10,13,’201810282 $’

STR1 DB 'tal'    ;Password 
STR2  DB "*$"

P1 LABEL BYTE      ;Start of data type
M1 DB 0FFH         ;Code so the user can type input. Assigning maximum length of array
L1 DB ?            ;used to Get the length of the entered String by user.
P11 DB 0FFH DUP (‘$’)  ;p11 is the name referred for the Array in the program
;LEA DX, STR2 ; display *
DATA ENDS

DISPLAY MACRO MSG
MOV AH,9
LEA DX,MSG
INT 21H 
ENDM

.CODE
ASSUME CS:CODE,DS:DATA

START:
 MOV AX,DATA
 MOV DS,AX

DISPLAY MSG1 

LEA DX,P1 
MOV AH,0H 
INT 21H 

LEA SI,STR1
LEA DI,P11

MOV CX,3
  
CHECK:
 MOV AL,[SI]
 CMP [DI],AL
 JNE WRONG
 INC SI
 INC DI
 LOOP CHECK

DISPLAY MSG3
DISPLAY MSG4

JMP EXIT

WRONG:
 DISPLAY MSG2
 JMP EXIT

EXIT: 
 MOV AH,4CH
 INT 21H
 CODE ENDS
 END START
```

Comment: `MOV AH,0H` `INT 21H` <-- Surely that's a typo? Wouldn't that terminate the program?

Comment: In any case, you can use `int 21h` subfunction 7 or 8 if you want to read characters without echo.